# Setting up Firefly (ruby link shortener) 2.0 on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra

I have a working install on my local machine, but was unable to do the same on heroku.

The only changes I've made:

- change hostname in firefly.yml to rxlcc.herokuapp.com
- comment out other dbs in Gemfile, only pg uncommented

my repo at: https://github.com/hayksaakian/rxlcc

github changelog: https://github.com/hayksaakian/rxlcc/commit/d2e2f926b228372a9ff7861e918bdf193a3c3bca

i'm guessing it's because there are no connections to the production db, but i'm unsure where i would add them

```
2012-12-31T05:36:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 36424`
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 27, col 0: `adapter = uri.scheme' (ArgumentError)
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:8:in `config'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:4:in `connect!'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
2012-12-31T05:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-12-31T05:36:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-12-31T05:36:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-12-31T05:41:04+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rxlcc.herokuapp.com fwd=71.212.33.130 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-12-31T05:41:05+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rxlcc.herokuapp.com fwd=71.212.33.130 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

my heroku addons:

```
heroku-postgresql:dev  HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY
```

---

Update:

I tried adding a line in lib/firefly/server.rb

```
  # suggested by iain on stackoverflow
  @config[:database_url] = ENV["DATABASE_URL"]
```

this didn't seem to change anything

https://github.com/hayksaakian/rxlcc/commit/638bb8b215cf09f7edbafc0f21e964dfc05f86f2

```
    2013-01-02T06:32:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2013-01-02T06:32:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 18667`
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 27, col 0: `adapter = uri.scheme' (ArgumentError)
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:8:in `config'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:4:in `connect!'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly/database.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/lib/firefly.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    2013-01-02T06:32:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
    2013-01-02T06:32:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-01-02T06:32:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-01-02T06:37:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rxlcc.herokuapp.com fwd=71.212.33.130 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2013-01-02T06:37:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rxlcc.herokuapp.com fwd=71.212.33.130 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the database url in under `host:` in the yml file. You can see the url in either your settings page on the Heroku site, or you can run `heroku config --app rxlcc` and look for DATABASE_URL.

**Note**: the instructions tell you to change the .gitignore and check in the .yml files if you're going to use Heroku. If you're going to keep secret keys in there then I wouldn't do this, but if you do, **don't make the repo a public one!** If anyone else knows a secret, you *need* to regenerate it.

Personally I would add anything secret via

```
heroku config:add SECRET_VARIABLE=blahblahblah --app rxlcc
```

and then read it into the app where it's needed via

```
my_secret_variable = ENV["SECRET_VARIABLE"]
```

I see the app sets the config at https://github.com/hayksaakian/rxlcc/blob/master/lib/firefly/server.rb#L209 and in a before block at https://github.com/hayksaakian/rxlcc/blob/master/lib/firefly/server.rb#L109. At either point you could try:

```
@config[:database_url] = ENV["DATABASE_URL"]
```

to add in any secret vars.

Comment: I also thought the hostname variable in firefly.yml should point to the public domain not the database though

Comment: Yes, the `hostname` in firefly.yml is for the public domain url. The `host` is database.yml should point to the database server. In the examples this is assumed to be localhost, but in production that will  rarely be so. If you run `heroku config` and get the value of HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL and add that as DATABASE_URL if it's not there it'll make it easier to port around too. I do that with all of my apps if DATABASE_URL is not there.

Comment: thanks for the help. after talking to the firefly developer, it seems like 2.0 just isnt ready for production yet. I'm using https://github.com/ariejan/firefly-heroku now without a hitch.

Comment: Ah yes, he's done what I suggested in the rackup file instead. Glad it's working for you.